# How to COUNTIFS for specific weekday AND time range?

Tags: excel

I am trying to write a formula that counts all of the entries on a table that are on a specific weekday AND within a certain time range. Below is a sample table:

[image: Sample table]

How would I write a formula to count all entries that occurred on a Monday between the times of 02:00-20:00?

I can get it to count entries within the time range with a simple COUNTIFS using >= and <= within the range using `=COUNTIFS(Table1[Time], ">=02:01",Table1[Time],"<=19:59")`, but am struggling adding the third conditional statement of weekday. I have tried playing around with the WEEKDAY function without success.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot call a worksheet function in a criteria definition. So the easiest way would be adding a third column "Weekday" to your table, where you calculate the weekday, and then modify your `COUNTIFS` accordingly

Comment: Yes, Countifs only takes a range as the first of each pair of arguments, not an expression, so you can't use it here without creating a helper column https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(Table1[Date])=2)*(Table1[Time]>TIME(2,0,0))*(Table1[Time]<TIME(20,0,0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try-

```
=SUM((TEXT(Table1[Date],"dddd")="Monday")*(Table1[Time]>=TIME(2,0,0))*(Table1[Time]<=TIME(19,59,0)))
```

May need CSE entry for older version of excel. CSE means enter formula by pressing `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]